# Data Vault 2.0 - why do we need business vault when we have information marts?

Tags: database, dimensional-modeling, data-vault

What's the purpose of having a business vault when we can apply business rules while building information marts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine several departments which share some business rules.

Either it would be possible to implement those common business rules for each and every `Information Mart`.

Or, using the `Business Vault` layer, there would be a central point for business rules and their implementation. All `Information Marts` can get data directly out of the `Business Vault` and put it into their structure. If the business rule changes, there is only one point which has to be changed.

If one department needs another business rule, a second one can be created directly in the `Business Vault` and would be available for other purposes as well.

Also the metadata documentation would only be a bit slimmer since not every `Information Mart` would show their own implementation of business rules.

So it is an architectural decision to put the rules as far downstream as possible for other following components.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @tobi6.